# How to create a button in a child window after calling from main window event handler?

Tags: c++, win32gui

I have a main window program that calls a child window after pressing O.K as shown in the below code snippet. MY question is how do i insert a button and edit field within this child window retrieve it back ? I understand for main windows this is done via WinProc. Is there a better way of doing via child windows ?

```
case IDOK:
            HINSTANCE hinst;
            HWND hWindow;
            hinst = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
            hWindow = CreateWindow
                (

                g_szClassName,
                TEXT("Configure Maze Properties"),
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                200, 100, 300, 228,
                hwnd,
                0,
                hinst,
                0
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two main possibilities:

- start populating the new windows from where you are. Simply pass `hWindow` as the parent window in [`CreateWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of the current `hwnd`.
- start populating the new window from within its own winproc message handler, by reacting on `WM_CREATE` as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_3.shtm). This requires however that you've registered `g_szClassName` as a separate class for the child window, with its own callback function.

By the way, the tutorial shows you how to create the button and a textbox.

The second alternative requires slightly more work, but makes the child window more self-contained, which lead to cleaner code and better reusability.